# How to hide title column in Sharepoint list created by Asset Provisioning in Sharepoint Framework?

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, sharepointframework

When my deployed webpart is installed I need sharepoint to auto create a list with Title Column hidden or name changed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to provision some items with elements.xml in spfx please check the fallowing steps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package
To make title column not required and hidden You need to add Content type on which Your list will be build and in this CT You need to reference Title column as hidden and not required like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ContentType ID="0x010019DBC07DC85E425FAC393333BE5C537A" 
               Name="SomeCT" 
               Group="SomeGroup" 
               Description="Some CT" 
               Inherits="FALSE" Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" Hidden="TRUE" Required="FALSE" />      
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```